# Customise scrollbar thumb to be at bottom by using css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible for the scrollbar thumb to be by default at the bottom of the page by just using css and webkit. I used jquery to do so but that is not giving me the desired result and i want to do it using css

Here is my css code

```
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
background-color: #000000;
 }
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: #555;
}
```

Here is the jquery code i used to achieve this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var refreshIntervalId=null;
  refreshIntervalId =  setInterval(function(){
      var element = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
      if (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight || element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth) {
        $('#mydiv').animate({
                   scrollTop: $(document).height()
               },
                'slow');
               return false;
      }
    }, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: You want the page to be scrolled to the bottom automatically? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @SujanSundareswaran yes

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you can do this—

`$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},"slow");`

That's it.

Comment: Its not happening in my case.I'm using a div which scrolls to the bottom only when overflow occurs.For that i used the function above to listen constantly for the overflow.

Comment: $('#mydiv').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},"slow"); is not working for me